# MDX formula for calculating All-Commodity Volume (%ACV)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to create a measure for the All-Commodity Volume (ACV) indicator. The formula is the following :

Total Sales of Resellers Who Sold a Product / Total Sales of All Resellers

Let's take an example, for instance the product "LL Touring Frame - Blue, 44" from AdventureWorks2012DW Cube.

We can see it is sold by 14 resellers

[image]

These 14 resellers together make 2 706 909 $ of the sales

[image]

If I take all the resellers, they make 80 450 596 $ of the sales

[image]

My ACV measure would return 2 607 909 / 80 450 596 = 2%  for the product "LL Touring Frame - Blue, 44", which means it present at the resellers who make 2% of my indirect sales.

What I'm looking for is the MDX expression which takes the "Reseller Sales Amount for all products" instead of the reseller sales amount for the selected product, but only if the "Reseller Sales Amount of the selected product is not null".

[image]

So far, thanks the help of the community I could make a query which gives me the correct result if I filter on some specific products :

WITH SET ActiveStores As NonEmpty(
            [DimStore].[Store].[Store]
            , { ([DimProduct].[Product].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Sales])} 
        )

MEMBER ACV AS SUM(ActiveStores, [Measures].[Store Sales]) / [Measures].[Store Sales]

SELECT NON EMPTY ACV  ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([DimProduct].[Product].[Product].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DimProduct].[Product].&[ HAMAC DE VOYAGE] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube])

This query returns an ACV of 9% for the filtered product. However, if I remove the filter by putting only FROM [Cube], the ACV becomes 100% for all the products, even the one which was 9% with the previous query.

It is like the ActiveStores set is binded with the WHERE clause but not the ROWS Axis.

Regards

Comment: I'm not understanding something. Your MDX looks good. Can't you just replace [Measures].[Distinct Number of Stores] with [Measures].[Sales] and be done?

Comment: GregGalloway, if I do that I get the amount of sales of the selected product in the stores where it is sold, what I need is the sales of all product in the stores where the selected product is sold. I have updated my post by adding more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution this way :

I have added an aggregated fact (Store Sales) as an attribute of dimension Store. Created a Measure Store Sales out of it, then created a calculated measure with the following expression :

```
SUM(NonEmpty(
            [DimStore].[Store].[Store]
            ,([Measures].[Sales])
        ), [Measures].[Store Sales]) / (ROOT([DimStore]), [Measures].[Store Sales])
```

Answer (score 0):

To find members where Sales is not null you can use the `NonEmpty` function:

```
NonEmpty(
  [Stores].[Stores].members
  ,(
     [Product].[Product].[ProductA]
   , [Measures].[Sales]
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks whytheq for your reply, unfortunately, the result of this expression is always null.

Comment: Thanks again, but stills returns null :/

Comment: please add your full `mdx` script to the question

Comment: I have updated my post. Thanks again for you help whytheq.

Comment: @user2018454 I'm not too familiar with this function `ROOT`

Comment: Maybe we can do it differently, I have added an aggregated fact (Store Sales Amount) as an attribute of the store dimension, so now I have a new column id the store dimension with these values :

- Store 1 : 30M

- Store 2 : 40M

- Store 3 : 60M

I would like a measure which can provide the sum of this attribute.

If Product A was sold in Stores 1 and 3, then the measure should return 90M (30 + 60)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Sum(
 [Store].[Store].[Store].Members,
 IIF(
  IsEmpty([Measures].[Sales]),
  Null,
  (
    ROOT([Product])
   ,ROOT([Supplier])
   ,ROOT([Promotion])
   ,ROOT([Misc])
   ,[Measures].[Sales]
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think we are almost there, I have updated my post with a query which gives correct result but only if there is a product filtered, the purpose is to make it working without the filter.

Comment: @user2018454 which stores do you count if the user has not filtered to a particular product? All stores? Not clear what you mean by "working without a filter"